# Trying to call a sub in the main sub in a loop. Getting error

Tags: excel, vba

I wanna copy data from 1 worksheet to another in a certain way without using the clipboard. For that I am trying to call a sub in my main sub and use it in a loop.
I am getting an error if I call the sub multiple times or in a loop. If I call it only once, it works fine. The error is:

> Runtime Error 424 “Object Required”

The code I want to run is given below.

```
Sub CopyValues(rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range)
 
    rngTarget.Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, rngSource.Columns.Count).Value = rngSource.Value
 
End Sub    
Sub Newsheet ()

 Numrows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        
    ' Select cell a1.
    Range("A1").Select
    ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
    irow = 1
     
     Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
      
     For RowCount = 1 To Numrows
            
            Call CopyValues(Sheet1.Range("A" & RowCount, "G" & RowCount), Sheet2.Range("A" & irow))
            
            Call CopyValues(Sheet1.Range("H" & RowCount, "AF" & RowCount), Sheet2.Range("A" & irow + 1))
            
            Call CopyValues(Sheet1.Range("AG" & RowCount, "BL" & RowCount), Sheet2.Range("A" & irow + 2))
            
            irow = irow + 3

      Next

End Sub
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure what you're actually trying to do. You add a new sheet, but then never do anything to it.

Comment: If you see, the target range is in sheet 2. So I am trying to copy values from sheet 1 and pasting them in sheet 2 in a certain manner.

Comment: I think you are assuming that `Sheet2` is a reference to the new sheet, which is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declare you variables and create variables for the worksheets:

```
Sub Newsheet()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = ActiveSheet
    
    Numrows = sht1.Range("A1", sht1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
    Dim irow As Long
    irow = 1

    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht2 = Sheets.Add(After:=sht1)
    
    Dim RowCount As Long    
    For RowCount = 1 To Numrows
    
        Call CopyValues(sht1.Range("A" & RowCount, "G" & RowCount), sht2.Range("A" & irow))
        Call CopyValues(sht1.Range("H" & RowCount, "AF" & RowCount), sht2.Range("A" & irow + 1))
        Call CopyValues(sht1.Range("AG" & RowCount, "BL" & RowCount), sht2.Range("A" & irow + 2))
        
        irow = irow + 3
    
    Next

End Sub
```